# Need to save the frame as an image in the specified folder during save

Tags: java, graphics, frame, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I want to store the frame image in a filename which is specified when the save button is clicked, right now i am getting it saved in the E folder of my computer as "Screen.png", but i want the user to give the option to specify the name of the file and save the image to the specified folder. how can i do it?

```
JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
        int option = save.showSaveDialog(save);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {

                BufferedImage awtImage = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                frame.paint(awtImage.getGraphics());
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(awtImage, "png", new File("E://Screen.png"));
                    System.out.println("panel saved as image");
                } catch (Exception evt) {
                    System.out.println("panel not saved" + evt.getMessage());
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) { // again, catch any exceptions and...
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the JFileChooser.

The call to show of a JFileChooser blocks the thread until the user selects a folder, so you can use the selected file straight on the same method.

The ImageIO class has the following write methods:

static boolean  write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, File output)
Writes an image using an arbitrary ImageWriter that supports the given format to a File.

static boolean  write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, ImageOutputStream output)
Writes an image using the an arbitrary ImageWriter that supports the given format to an ImageOutputStream.

static boolean  write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, OutputStream output)
Writes an image using an arbitrary ImageWriter that supports the given format to an OutputStream.

In your case, BufferedWriter is a OutputStream that you can just use.

And remember to flush() and close() your streams after that.

EDIT: THE ANSWER

```
BufferedImage awtImage = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                frame.paint(awtImage.getGraphics());
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(awtImage, "png", new File("E://Screen.png"));
                    System.out.println("panel saved as image");
                } catch (Exception evt) {
                    System.out.println("panel not saved" +     evt.getMessage());
                }
```

Should be:

```
BufferedImage awtImage = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(),frame.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                File selected = save.getSelectedFile();
                frame.paint(awtImage.getGraphics());
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(awtImage, "png", selected);
                    System.out.println("panel saved as image at: " + selected.getPath());
                } catch (Exception evt) {
                    System.out.println("panel not saved" +     evt.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: I am using the JFileChooser at the beginning of this code and specified "BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));" but how to use "outFile" in the imageIO to write to the file?

Comment: Okay, check the ansewr

Comment: It is not interrupting if the filename already exists! how to do it?

Comment: Use print or printAll instead of paint, there're not double buffered to start with and paint can cause issues if it's not displayable

Comment: Well, check if file.exists() early and warn the user to override it or choose another one.